# Why scanf waits only when stdin is set to "/dev/pts/*"

Tags: c, linux

```
int main()
{
int fd=open("/dev/pts/0",O_RDWR);
if(fd==-1){
  printf("Error");
  exit(1);
}
dup2(fd,0);
char c[20];
printf("reading from file\n");
scanf("%s",c);
}
```

In above code `"/dev/pts/0"` is set as stdin.scanf behaves normally.
But when I set to filename like `"inp.txt"` it doesn't wait directly reads whatever it finds.
Why is that like that?What to do if I want to make it wait?

Comment: What is it supposed to wait for when reading from a file?

Answer (score 3):

When you read from a file, *the data is already there*, so why would `scanf()` wait?  Or any other way of reading the file?

`/dev/pts/<i>N</i>` are Unix 98 pseudoterminals, which by their very nature are *interactive*.  A blocking read from one waits for *interactive input*.  A nonblocking read would just tell you that there is no data to read right now.

If you create a pipe between processes, associate the read end with an `stdio` `FILE` handle via `fdopen()`, you can use `scanf()` to scan data from the pipe.  That, too, will wait for input, unless all write ends of the pipe are closed (then the `scanf` will fail with end-of-input).  So, there is nothing special about the pseudoterminals in this respect.